# JQuery autocomplete suddenly stopped working

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

The autocomplete was working well for months, suddenly it stopped recognizing 'autocomplete' method.
This is the error I'm getting:
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Default.aspx
Reference to the local js file was working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now that it stopped working I tried the online reference, with no avail.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Javascript code:

```
        var availableTags = [
              "ActionScript",
              "AppleScript",
              "Asp",
        ];
        $("#MyTextBox").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength: 0,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $get("MyTextBox").value = ui.item.value;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a race condition? Where is the autocomplete initialization being done? Is it possible that it is now getting run before jQuery-UI is loaded?

Comment: It is not possible. The textbox is in a datagrid, and is visible on mouseClick.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in one of my js files which was preventing the jquery from loading, my bad.
I removed the error line, and every works fine now.